# Solve the partial differential equation $(3x^2y -x ^2)dx+dy = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation
$$(3x^2y -x ^2)dx+dy = 0 \tag1 $$
$$\text{Here}\quad M(x,y) = 3x^2y -x ^2, \quad\text {and} \quad N(x,y) =1 $$
$${\partial M \over \partial y} = 3x^2\quad \text{and}\quad {\partial N \over \partial x} = 0 $$
$${1\over N}\left({\partial M \over \partial y} -{\partial N \over \partial x}\right) = 3x^2 $$
is a function of $x$ alone so the integrating factor is 
$$ I(x,y) = e^{\int3x^2} = e^{x^3} $$ 
Therefore equation $(1)$ becomes,
$$(3x^2ye^{x^3} -x ^2e^{x^3})dx+e^{x^3}dy = 0$$
Further how may I solve this as an exact diff. equation?
I am following Schaum's outlines differential equations Richard Bronson.

Comment: I think this complicates matters a fair bit. It can be solved by variable separable method.

Comment: I am lost, cannot you integrate differential forms $f(x)dx+g(y)dy=0$ on the spot? Your example is veeeeerry close to that, no?

Answer (score 4):

$$(3x^2y -x ^2)dx+dy = 0 $$
This is a separable ODE :

Apart the trivial solution $y=\frac{1}{3}$, one can devide by $(3y-1)$ :
$$x^2dx=\frac{dy}{1-3y} $$
I suppose that you can continue...

Comment: As it is given as an exercise in chapter of exact diff. equ. so, I wanna solve it as exact diff. equation.

Comment: @Ali Jan : OK. But it was not clearly specified at first.

Comment: And this solution provides exactly that, that is, an exact differential equation nearly equivalent to yours...

Answer (score 2):

After multiplying by integration factor: $e^{x^3}$, the given D.E. becomes in the exact form of D.E. hence, integrate as follows $$(3x^2ye^{x^3}-x^2e^{x^3})dx+e^{x^3}\ dy=0$$
$$\int_{\text{y=constant}} (3x^2ye^{x^3}-x^2e^{x^3})dx+\int_{\text{terms free of x}}e^{x^3}\ dy=C$$
$$(3y-1)\int x^2e^{x^3}dx=C$$

$$\frac{3y-1}{3}\int 3x^2e^{x^3}dx=C$$
$$\frac{3y-1}{3}\int e^{x^3}(3x^2\ dx)=C$$

let $x^3=t\implies 3x^2\ dx=dt$
$$\frac{3y-1}{3}\int e^{t}dt=C$$
$$\frac{3y-1}{3}e^{t}=C$$

$$\color{}{\frac{(3y-1)e^{x^3}}{3}=C}$$

$$\color{red}{y=Ce^{-x^3}+\frac 13}$$

Comment: thank you dear Harash, May You explain the last 2 steps for me, Indeed I was stuck at the same place.

Comment: Answere is y = ce^{x^3} + 1/3

Comment: @AliJan: I have edited the answer, I hope it's now clear to you. However feel free to ask for further doubt

Comment: @AliJan: You should recheck your answer. it should be $ce^{-x^3}+\frac 13$ not $ce^{x^3}+\frac 13$